# PayPal error with custom fee

Tags: magento2, paypal

I'm facing an issue where I'm adding a custom fee to totals and updating paypal with the following plugin:

```
class UpdateCustomFeeForOrderPayPal
{
    protected $_checkoutSession;
    const AMOUNT_SUBTOTAL = 'subtotal';
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
    ) {
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }

    public function afterGetAmounts($cart,$result)
    {
        $quote = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote();
        $paymentMethod = $quote->getPayment()->getMethod();
        $paypalMehodList = ['payflowpro','payflow_link','payflow_advanced','braintree_paypal','paypal_express_bml','payflow_express_bml','payflow_express','paypal_express'];

        // to check the paypal payment method
        if(in_array($paymentMethod,$paypalMehodList)){
            $result[self::AMOUNT_SUBTOTAL] = $result[self::AMOUNT_SUBTOTAL] + $quote->getFee();

        }

        return $result;
    }

    public function beforeGetAllItems($cart)
    {
        $quote      = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote();

        $feePrice = $quote->getFee();

        if ($feePrice > 0) {
            $cart->addCustomItem(__("Extra Fee"), 1, $feePrice);
        }
    }
}
```

This unfortunately doesn't play well with PayPal, I'm getting the following response:

```
main.DEBUG: array (
  'url' => 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp',
  'SetExpressCheckout' => 
  array (
    'PAYMENTACTION' => 'Sale',
    'AMT' => '108.85',
    'CURRENCYCODE' => 'USD',
    'RETURNURL' => 'http://test.com/us/paypal/express/return/',
    'CANCELURL' => 'http://test.com/us/paypal/express/cancel/',
    'INVNUM' => 'US-00050186',
    'SOLUTIONTYPE' => 'Mark',
    'GIROPAYCANCELURL' => 'http://test.com/us/paypal/express/cancel/',
    'GIROPAYSUCCESSURL' => 'http://test.com/us/checkout/onepage/success/',
    'BANKTXNPENDINGURL' => 'http://test.com/us/checkout/onepage/success/',
    'SHIPPINGAMT' => '9.99',
    'ITEMAMT' => '85.43',
    'TAXAMT' => '7.99',
    'L_NUMBER0' => NULL,
    'L_NAME0' => 'ExtraFee',
    'L_QTY0' => 1,
    'L_AMT0' => '5.44',
    'BUSINESS' => NULL,
    'NOTETEXT' => NULL,
    'EMAIL' => 'test@gmail.com',
    'FIRSTNAME' => 'test',
    'LASTNAME' => 'test',
    'MIDDLENAME' => NULL,
    'SALUTATION' => NULL,
    'SUFFIX' => NULL,
    'COUNTRYCODE' => 'US',
    'STATE' => 'NY',
    'CITY' => 'New York',
    'STREET' => 'New York',
    'ZIP' => '10013',
    'PHONENUM' => '17623838372',
    'SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE' => 'US',
    'SHIPTOSTATE' => 'NY',
    'SHIPTOCITY' => 'New York',
    'SHIPTOSTREET' => 'New York',
    'SHIPTOZIP' => '10013',
    'SHIPTOPHONENUM' => '17623838372',
    'SHIPTOSTREET2' => '',
    'STREET2' => '',
    'SHIPTONAME' => 'test test',
    'ADDROVERRIDE' => 1,
    'METHOD' => 'SetExpressCheckout',
    'VERSION' => '72.0',
    'USER' => '****',
    'PWD' => '****',
    'SIGNATURE' => '****',
    'BUTTONSOURCE' => 'Magento_Cart_Community',
  ),
  'response' => 
  array (
    'TIMESTAMP' => '2019-02-08T15:31:17Z',
    'CORRELATIONID' => 'de43685675249',
    'ACK' => 'Failure',
    'VERSION' => '72.0',
    'BUILD' => '51752370',
    'L_ERRORCODE0' => '10413',
    'L_SHORTMESSAGE0' => 'Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details.',
    'L_LONGMESSAGE0' => 'The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts.',
    'L_SEVERITYCODE0' => 'Error',
  ),
) [] []
```

But the totals of the cart do match:
9.99 + 85.43 + 7.99 + 5.44 = 108.85

I don't understand what is the issue. Does anyone have an idea what's going on?